# Move virtual box default machine folder

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtualization

I have installed Virtual box on Windows XP and by default machine folder is pointing to C: drive of my Windows XP which and size of that is 13GB.

I would like to move this to my D drive. How can I do that without causing any damage to existing settings.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default machine folder using the menu option File->Preferences, under the General tab.

Once you change that value just copy everything from the original location to the new location.  After you copy the files you may need to update the hard disks in each of your virtual machines to point to the new locations.

Comment: After moving to new location can I remove all the files from old location? Because when I try to delete the folder I get Vbox.log is still being used by another program.

Comment: Yes, there should be no reason to keep them there.

Comment: After removing old location folder and when I try to start OS in VB, `I am getting FATAL:Could not read from the boot meduim! System halted.`

Comment: Open the Virtual Media Manager from the File menu and make sure everything looks ok there.

Comment: Under Media Manager I cannot find anything under Hard Drives, cannot find an option to copy or modify because it is greyed out.

Comment: You may need to re-add the hard disks to the machines, they will be in `<new data dir>\VM Name\VM Name.vdi` if you used the Virtual Box default disks.